# When I get a badge notification in the Feed of the android app relating to a specific post tell me which one it was

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, android-app-feed

I got a badge today (yay!) for a specific question.

On the website the notification has the title of the question as a link as part of the notification.

On the android app all I get is:

> You earned a new badge!
>
> Popular Question - Asked a question with 1,000 views

---

I think the display should be similar to the website:

> You've earned the "Popular Question" badge for Under UK Building Codes are you allowed to add an additional stopcock?

Where "Under UK...." would be the question title.

Tapping the notification in the feed should open the post in the app.

Comment: I've created the tag android-app-feed to refer to the feed in the android app (as opposed to the RSS feed). If you don't think that's a good tag feel free to edit/remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't made a change to what is displayed, but we'll discuss this. The feed design is still very much in flux. But clicking the badge notification will now open the correspond post (if the badge relates to one) in version 0.1.16, so the most important part of this is completed.